# How to upload a youtube video using youtube data v3 api with android studio

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been searching for a way to upload a youtube video with api, I found youtube data v3, created cloud application, added oauth and got the api keys, I also created credentials (client id and client secret for android application) but i am failing to find a sample of java code that uploads a video to youtube, I found a [python](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) sample written by google.

I tried searching google docs, i also tried using chatgpt but as always it spits out some garbage code that never works.

I found this old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478060/upload-video-to-youtube-via-android-studio) but the links seems to be no longer the same

Comment: The Google documentation site links in the old answer require some navigation. From your link select 'Upload a Video', change the 'Resource' dropdown to 'Video' and 'Method' dropdown to 'insert',  read docs, then on the right hand side panel add required params, then scroll down to bottom and click on 'show code' (or click on the dash line box at the top) and you'll get a new screen with a 'Java' tab. Change request parameters as required.

Comment: @MorrisonChang this code is for java desktop not android, I cannot use the libraries provided for android

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199896/295004 but the library does support Android: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client#supported-java-environments

Comment: check [media upload](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-upload)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload videos on Youtube to a particular youtube account on Android programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199496/how-to-upload-videos-on-youtube-to-a-particular-youtube-account-on-android-progr)